# Doxygen style comments in Kate

Tags: editor, comments, doxygen, shortcut, kate

Kate features a very handy shortcut (Ctrl+D) to apply single- and multi-line comment to the selected region of text. How can I configure Kate to apply doxygen style comments in C/C++ source files?

```
/**
 * reduces the channel complexity
 * args: None
 * returns: None
 */
void Channel::reduce();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there might be direct doxygen support in the works (for version 1.30.2). I will test it when I have access to my linux/kde box at home.

http://www.kde-files.org/content/show.php/Updated+Doxygen+highlighting?content=106727